Hilt gives class cast exception when try to start an activity inside an android lib
I am developing an android sdk and using hilt inside my lib.
Inside my lib, there is an activity and inside my activity, I manage lib related fragments internally.
If I build my lib without proguard and implement it inside consumer app, everything works fine.
But when I build my lib with proguard, consumer app crashes when I start libs activity.
Here is exception
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.consumerappdemo.hiltdemo.DaggerHiltDemoApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ActivityCImpl cannot be cast to com.mylib.full_sdk_demo.DemoActivity_GeneratedInjector

This is the proguard file for my lib
-keep class dagger.hilt.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class * implements dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent { *; }
-keep class * implements dagger.hilt.internal.ComponentBuilder { *; }
-keep class dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager { *; }
-keep class dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager { *; }

-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keep class dagger.hilt.internal.** { *; }
-keep class dagger.hilt.android.internal.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class com.mylib.full_sdk_demo.**_GeneratedInjector { *; }

-keep class dagger.hilt.internal.* { *; }
-keep class dagger.hilt.android.internal.* { *; }

-keep @dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel class * { *; }

Hilt version: 2.52
gradle version: 8.5.2
